# Declare an external module function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to declare an external module which has no existing typings, but am missing something.

The library exports a function which takes no arguments and returns a string.

I'm trying to define it using this in a `.d.ts` file:

```
declare module "cuid" {
    export function cuid(): string;
}
```

In my code, I have `import * as cuid from 'cuid';`

Yet on the line where I use it, `cuid()` I get an error:

`error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Use the definition with `export function cuid`

This syntax matches with your declaration:

```
import {cuid} from 'cuid';
```

[Here is a good introduction to ES6 modules.](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/)

## Or use a definition with `export =`

Try:

```
declare module "cuid" {
  function cuid(): string;
  export = cuid;
}
```

... Then use it: `import cuid = require('cuid')`.

[Here is the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require).